# Rspecで音声ファイルの設定が出来ず、ActiveStorage::IntegrityError:が解消できない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, wsl

#### 解決したいこと

現在ポートフォリオ作成中のプログラミング入門者です。テストを書くのにRspecを使ってみようと考えたので、Rspecを使い、テストを作成しています。ですが、音声ファイルの検証テストを書く際にエラーが起こってしまいました。

#### エラー

```
Failures:

  1) DictumUser test for DictumUser when user input invalid parameter when user is deleted gogaku is deleted too
     Failure/Error: expect(Gogaku.count).to eq 1

       expected: 1
            got: 0

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/dictum_user_spec.rb:126:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Gogaku test for gogaku gogaku should be valid
     Failure/Error: expect(gogaku).to be_valid
       expected #<Gogaku id: nil, subject: "English", body: "in trip", file: nil, answer: "none", dictum_user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Dictum user can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/gogaku_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'

Finished in 0.31763 seconds (files took 1.52 seconds to load)
11 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/dictum_user_spec.rb:119 # DictumUser test for DictumUser when user input invalid parameter when user is deleted gogaku is deleted too
rspec ./spec/models/gogaku_spec.rb:13 # Gogaku test for gogaku gogaku should be valid
```

#### 該当するソースコード

```
#/spec/factories/dictum_users.rb

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :dictum_user do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "user#{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "test#{n}@example.com" }
    password { "password" }
    password_confirmation { "password" }
  end

#/spec/factories/gogakus.rb

 FactoryBot.define do
  factory :gogaku do
      subject {"English"}
      body {"in trip"}
      after(:build) do |gogaku|
          gogaku.file = fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'files', 'Night_Sea.mp3'), 'audio/mp3', :binary)
      end
      answer {"none"}
      association :dictum_user
  end
end

# spec/models/dictum_user_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe DictumUser, type: :model do
    describe "test for DictumUser" do
        context "should be valid" do
            it "create instance accurately" do
                expect(user).to be_valid
            end
        end
        context "when user input invalid parameter" do
            context "when name which user input is empty" do
                user = FactoryBot.build(:dictum_user, name: "")
                it " regard the user as invalid" do
                    expect(user).not_to be_valid
                end
            end
            context "when name which user input is too long" do
                user = FactoryBot.build(:dictum_user, name: "a"*51)
                it " regard the user as invalid" do
                    expect(user).not_to be_valid
                end
            end
            
            context "when email which user input is empty" do
                user = FactoryBot.build(:dictum_user, email: "")
                it "regard the user as invalid" do
                    expect(user).not_to be_valid
                end
            end
            context "when email which user input is invalid format" do
                user = FactoryBot.build(:dictum_user, email: "email.com")
                it "regard the user as invalid" do
                    expect(user).not_to be_valid
                end
            end
            context "when email which user input is too long" do
                user = FactoryBot.build(:dictum_user, email: "a"*244+"@example.com")
                it "regard the user as invalid" do
                    expect(user).not_to be_valid
                end
            end
            context "when password which user input is empty " do
                user = FactoryBot.build(:dictum_user, password: " "*6, password_confirmation: " "*6)
                it "regard the user as invalid" do
                    expect(user).not_to be_valid
                end
            end
            context "when password which user input is too short" do
                user = FactoryBot.build(:dictum_user, password: "hoge", password_confirmation: "hoge")
                it "regard the user as invalid" do
                    expect(user).not_to be_valid
                end
            end
            context "when email which user input isn`t unique" do
                user = FactoryBot.build(:dictum_user)
                it "regard the user as invalid" do
                    user.save
                    user2 = user.dup
                    user2.email = user2.email.upcase
                    user2.save
                    expect(user2).not_to be_valid
                end
            end
            context "when user is deleted" do
                user = FactoryBot.build(:dictum_user)
                gogaku = FactoryBot.build(:gogaku, dictum_user: user)
                
                it "gogaku is deleted too" do
                    expect(Gogaku.count).to eq 1
                    user.destroy
                    expect(Gogaku.count).to eq 0
                end
            end
        end
    end     
end

#/spec/models/gogaku_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Gogaku, type: :model do
  describe "test for gogaku" do
    let(:dictum_user) { FactoryBot.build(:dictum_user) }
    let(:gogaku) { FactoryBot.build(:gogaku, dictum_user: dictum_user) }
    it "gogaku should be valid" do
      expect(gogaku).to be_valid
    end
  end
end


　#gogaku.rb

class Gogaku < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :dictum_user
    default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
    validates :subject,presence:true
    validates :body,   presence:true
    has_one_attached :file
    validates :dictum_user_id, presence: true
    validates :file,presence:true
    validates :file,size:         { less_than: 5.megabytes,
                                      message: "should be less than 5MB" }
end

#
```

#### 自分で試したこと

https://gist.github.com/h-sakano/50092b1c17fe8ddc0bbe5382fb8587a4
https://qiita.com/h-sakano/items/fc297f91a7bafc0b4d6d
・最初にこの方たちの記事を参考にさせていただきました。ですが、私の場合、

```
# spec/factories/dictum_users.rb
after(:build) do |gogaku|
        gogaku.file = fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'files', 'Night_Sea.mp3'), 'audio/mpeg', :binary)
    end
```

このように記述してもエラーが直りませんでした。
・次に
https://qiita.com/tatematsu-k/items/1cdd946cd38e69d16340
この方の記事を参考にさせていただきました。rails6.1.5を使っていたので以下を追及

```
#rails_helper.rb

FactoryBot::SyntaxRunner.class_eval do
    include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
    include ActiveSupport::Testing::FileFixtures
  end
```

ですが、エラーが直りません。

・なぜか「when user is deleted gogaku is deleted too」の部分でDictum_userが空になっているというエラーが出ます。これはモデルでhas_manyの関係になっていることが原因かと考えられます（DictumUserが親Gogakuが子）。
https://qiita.com/takehanKosuke/items/ae324483e7f9451bf6a7
https://qiita.com/__kotaro_/items/adbc355bfb550b8b2150
https://qiita.com/johnslith/items/c0b2a9b8ce8770e5d317
こちらの方たちの記事を参考にさせていただき、関連付けが正しくできているか確認しました。恐らくできていると思いますが、なぜか上手く行きません。

#### その他

・ruby3.0.3 rails6.1.5 環境構築はDockerで行いました。wsl2のUbuntuを使っています。
・また、推奨されていませんが、マルチポストをしています。
https://teratail.com/questions/rs7c1n0nhk64nu

#### 追記

#### 追記

https://insyokuprogram.com/2021/08/08/%E3%80%90ruby-on-rails%E3%80%91to-be-valid-but-got-errors-user-cant-be-blank-%E3%80%90rspec%E3%80%91%E3%81%8C%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E4%BB%B6/
こちらの方の記事を参考にさせていただき、buildと記述している部分をcreateに変更したところエラーが変化しました。

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/dictum_user_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: gogaku = FactoryBot.create(:gogaku, dictum_user: user)

ActiveStorage::IntegrityError:
  ActiveStorage::IntegrityError
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-6.1.5/lib/active_storage/service/disk_service.rb:159:in `ensure_integrity_of'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-6.1.5/lib/active_storage/service/disk_service.rb:22:in `block in upload'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-6.1.5/lib/active_storage/service.rb:155:in `instrument'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-6.1.5/lib/active_storage/service/disk_service.rb:20:in `upload'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-6.1.5/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:253:in `upload_without_unfurling'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-6.1.5/lib/active_storage/attached/changes/create_one.rb:26:in `upload'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-6.1.5/lib/active_storage/attached/model.rb:77:in `block in has_one_attached'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-6.2.1/lib/factory_bot/evaluation.rb:18:in `create'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-6.2.1/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
# <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-6.2.1/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-6.2.1/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:43:in `run'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-6.2.1/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-6.2.1/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/factory_bot-6.2.1/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:28:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
# ./spec/models/dictum_user_spec.rb:117:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/models/dictum_user_spec.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/models/dictum_user_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/models/dictum_user_spec.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/models/dictum_user_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00009 seconds (files took 1.79 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

現在ここでデバッグ中です。

プログラミング入門者なので何かしら間違えた認識をしているかもしれません。何かしらアドバイスがあればよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

無事に解決出来ました。
https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/na2gu1/anyone_facing_activestorageintegrityerror_recently/
こちらの方の記事を参考にさせていただき、下記の通りにコードを書いたところ無事に動きました。

```
 # src/spec/factories/gogakus.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :gogaku do
      subject {"English"}
      body {"in trip"}
      after(:build) do |gogaku|
        image_file = File.open("./spec/fixtures/files/Night_Sea.mp3")
        gogaku.file.attach(io: image_file,filename: "Night_Sea.mp3",content_type: 'audio/mp3')
        image_file.rewind
      end
      answer {"none"}
      association :dictum_user
  end
end
```